# How to recover WCF client after WCF service restart?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've got static WCF client but I still can't understand how can I reset / recover it?

one of my tries:

```
if (Core.shed.State == CommunicationState.Faulted) {
    Core.shed.Close();
    Core.shed = new wcfClient();
    }
```

Doesn't work, I'm still getting

```
Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel'.
```

How should I reset it when my wcf service is alive again?

Comment: You can't close a channel that is in a faulted state - you have to abort it and create a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't close a WCF channel that is faulted - you must abort it and create a new one.  There is no way to recover that channel.

If you change this line of code from:

```
Core.shed.Close();
```

to:

```
Core.shed.Abort();
```

then the rest of your code should work.